# GStreamer decklinksrc doesn't work with v4l2loopback

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2loopback

I have Blackmagic intensity pro capture card and GoPro Hero 3 connected to it with HDMI.

I have installed v4l2loopback to /dev/video0.

Trying to capture video with decklinksrc to v4l2sink:

```
gst-launch decklinksrc mode=8 connection=1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0 sync=false
```

If I use mplayer:

```
 mplayer tv:// -tv device=/dev/video0
```

It works perfect, but Skype shows video0 as black screen. 
Cheese and flash don't show this device at all.

How can I get it work as webcam in flash and skype?

Answer (score 1):

If `mplayer` shows the video nicely and `skype` doesn't, then chances are high that you really hit a bug in *skype* (and/or *flash*).

Both *skype* and *flash* are known to be a bit botchy in their v4l2 imlementation.

Having said that, make sure that you are using a recent enough version of `v4l2loopback` (according to the [NEWS](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/master/NEWS)-file, you should have at least version *0.6.3*), as this will contain some hacks to make skype and flash work.